# C# access bytes of movie file frame by frame

Tags: c#, arrays, movie

Is there any fairly straight forward way of reading a movie file in C# and accessing the data as a byte array frame by frame? I'm not restricted to a specific format. The code has to be self-sufficient i.e. no third party libraries.

EDIT:

I need to play a local movie file (format is not important) as a texture in unity. I cannot use MovieTexture as it doesn't support mobile devices.

Comment: What data are you looking for? Do you mean the decoded image for each frame? That's not built into the framework, you do need third-party libraries for that.

Comment: I'm looking for the raw byte data. I'm trying to create a script for Unity that will play a video wrapped around a 3d object. I've done this before with raw byte data where the data is refreshed every update and then loaded into a texture. However I need to do this with a local movie file now.

Comment: What is "raw byte data"? If Unity supports decoding and playing video, you can just pass a stream to the video file...

Comment: Stop everything that you tried to do and take a look Unity's `MoveTexture` functionality. Trying to read the "raw byte data" is overkill when you're just trying to display a movie on a texture in *Unity*. (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html)

Comment: As Maximilian said, you are falling in to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should not be asking how to get the raw frames and instead be asking "how do I play a video as a texture?"

Comment: OK yes. I shall un XY my question. I need to play a local movie file (format is not important) as a texture in unity. @Maximilian Gerhardt I cannot use MovieTexture as it doesn't support mobile devices. Any thoughts?

Comment: Now this is just a question of googling. On the official repository hosted by the Unity Team, you may find an iOS implementation of a `VideoToTexture` renderer (https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/iosnativecodesamples/src/2c85a37958dc008c861ba6d49b26d9c8e8fa790c/NativeIntegration/Video/VideoPlayerTexture/?at=4.5-stable). Other than that, you may find several plugins in the asset store. (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032 , https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2449)

Comment: You should update your question with the new information, people should not need to read all the comments to be able to answer your question

Answer (score -1):

C# has no build-in video reader. But if a 3rd party library is unacceptable, you can find simple mp5 readers on codeproject (speaking from experience)

Comment: When I say a reader, I just mean some code (a method, class or namespace) which extracts the information from 1 or more files. Just a moment, I will find a link :)